# Python sciense, need choose web framework for B2C service: Django or Drupal

Tags: python, django, drupal, scipy, django-cms

Please help me decide what to choose for service.

I want to build site with scientific customer computational service: for every customer there will be personal account, different payment plans, customer will be able to adjust account settings that then will be passed as JSON/XML, they will input data, then service will do Data mining on it, showing results in the account.

For service i use Python's NumPy and SciPy-stack modules - i started to learn Python because it is best for sciense. I am Python newbie, 3 weeks long.
BUT for web-site i want to use Drupal, i learned it very well, it has so popular modules, that Django (or Django CMS, or Plone) don't has: Views, Context, Rules, Features, Token, social login from all social networks without creating account etc.

So, i don't want to﻿ do web programming, i want to concentrate on science with Python, i afraid if i choose framework like Django it will consume a lot of time to learn + i need to learn other Python modules for my primary work.

The question: how do i integrate Python and PHP's Drupal? How do i show computational results produced in Python in Drupal interface? Or maybe there is another way? (i know Mashape, but i need my own service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP's [Gearman](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gearman.examples-reverse.php) to build a job-queue and worker. Your very simple website will queue jobs for python to complete, then gearman can tell you when it's done.

Edit: Here is a more complete reference for Drupal: https://groups.drupal.org/node/36428

Comment: I will review it carefully, thanx

Answer (score 0):

Call the Python programs from PHP using the [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) command:

```
exec('science.py', $output);
```

Warning: this is a potential security hole if user parameters are passed to the program.

Comment: I will review this carefully, thanx